# Java - how to initialize a HashMap inside method by value

Tags: java, hashmap, copy, clone

I am new to Java and I tried a couple of ways to initialize my HashMap through a method, but every time after method executed, my Map is still empty, I can debug and see during my `LoadData` method execution, my maps are assigned with value from sub-method, however, when jumping out of the `LoadData`, my outer parameter becomes empty Map again

```
// file1.java
public Map<String, Student> getStudentWithIdMap() { ... }
public Map<String, Teacher> getTeacherWithIdMap() { ... }

public static void LoadData(Map<String, Student> studentMap, Map<String, Teacher> teacherMap, ...other Map)
{
     studentMap = getStudentWithIdMap();
     //I tried with studentMap.putAll(getStudentWithIdMap());
     // doing this triggers an exception like "UnsupportedOperationException"
     // I also tried studentMap = new HashMap<>(getStudentWithIdMap());
     teacherMap = getTeacherWithIdMap();
}

// file2.java
public void PrepareData() {
   Map<String, Student> studentMap = Collections.emptyMap();
   Map<String, Teacher> teacherMap = Collections.emptyMap();
   file1.LoadData(studentMap, teacherMap, ...);
}
```

What would be the reason and the best way to deal with the above scenario?

I get to know Java treats method as value type always, so if passing a class object and modify its value, it would be modified after method finishes execution, why a Map behaves differently?

Comment: You can modify the _contents_ of an object, but not an object itself.  That's the meaning of _passing references by value_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something like

```
 studentMap = getStudentWithIdMap();
```

The variable studentMap will point to the `Map` return by `getStudentwithIdMap();` that doesn't affect the Map referenced in variable `studentMap` in the `PrepareData` method.

To actually change that `Map` you need to insert the values into it.

E.g with:

```
public static void LoadData(Map<String, Student> studentMap, Map<String, Teacher> teacherMap, ...other Map)
{
     studentMap.putAll( getStudentWithIdMap() );
     //I tried with studentMap.putAll(getStudentWithIdMap());
     // doing this triggers an exception like "UnsupportedOperationException"
     // I also tried studentMap = new HashMap<>(getStudentWithIdMap());
     teacherMap.putAll( getTeacherWithIdMap() );
}
```

That will cause another Problem, because you initialized these variables with `Collection.emptyMap()`. You are not allowed to change that map, so writes will fail.

This can be fixed with:

```
public void PrepareData() {
   Map<String, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>();
   Map<String, Teacher> teacherMap = new HashMap<>();
   file1.LoadData(studentMap, teacherMap, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me:

```
public static void LoadData(Map<String, Student> studentMap, 
                            Map<String, Teacher> teacherMap, ...other Map) {
    studentMap = getStudentWithIdMap();
```

That assignment is assigning to a parameter.  It is a reference assignment.  It won't affect the map that was passed as a parameter.

`<Emphasis>` Java is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference. `</Emphasis>`

```
 //I tried with studentMap.putAll(getStudentWithIdMap());
 // doing this triggers an exception like "UnsupportedOperationException"
```

That is most likely because `Collections.emptyMap()` returns an **immutable** empty map.  You are trying to add elements to it.  That won't work.

The way to create an empty mutable map is to use `new HashMap<>()` or similar.

```
 // I also tried studentMap = new HashMap<>(getStudentWithIdMap());
```

That fails for the reason that your current attempt fails.  You are creating a new map, and assigning it to a parameter variable ... which is discarded when you return from `LoadData`.

---

What is the solution?

Possibly changing

```
  Map<String, Student> studentMap = Collections.emptyMap();
```

to

```
  Map<String, Student> studentMap = new HashMap<>();
```

will solve this ... but there is insufficient context in your Question to know if this is the *correct* solution.  (What are you really trying to do here?  Are the maps returned by `getStudentWithIdMap()` etcetera already populated?)

---

> I get to know Java treats method as value type always, so if passing a class object and modify its value, it would be modified after method finishes execution, why a Map behaves differently?

Actually, you need to go back to the textbook / tutorial / whatever where you learned that.  Re-read it.  You have missed something very important in your original reading / understanding.

When you pass an object (e.g. a `Map`) as a parameter, you are passing the reference to the object to the called method.  That reference is assigned to a local variable.

- When you assign a new reference to that local variable, it does not affect the state of the original object OR the variable in the caller where you got the reference from.
- To change the state of the object that you passed, you call a method on the object using the reference that you passed.

---

By the way `LoadData` is a style violation.  It should be named `loadData`.